# Dual module $M^\#$ contains non-torsion element if $M$ does

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, modules, free-modules

Let $R$ be a PID. Consider a ring homomorphism $R \to S$ that makes $S$ into a free $R$-algebra of rank $n$. Let $M$ be a finite $S$-module and denote by $M_{\mid R}$ its restriction as an $R$-module which is also free of rank $n$. Denote by $M^\#$ the $S$-module $\operatorname{Hom}_R(M_{\mid R},R)$ by multiplication into the argument. The latter means that for $f \in M^\#$ and $s \in S$ we define $(s \cdot f)(m) := f(sm)$.

*I have the following question/task:*

> Assume that there is non-zero $m \in M$ such that for all non-zero $s \in S$ we have $s m \neq 0$. Show that there is an element $f \in M^\#$ such that for all non-zero $s \in S$ we have $s \cdot f \neq 0$.

---

*A sufficient condition:*
If the intersection of the free $R$-module $mS$ of rank $n$ with $\ker(f)$ (which should be of rank $n-1$ as long as $f \neq 0$) is trivial, we have found $f \in M^\#$ with the intended property. But is it possible that $mS \cap \ker(f) \neq \{0\}$ for all $f \in M^\#$?

Comment: @SMM Yes, the assumption is that $M$ is a finite $S$-module. Moreover, I defined the $S$-module structure of $M^\#$ to be given by $S \times M^\# \to M^\#$, where the tuple $(s,x \mapsto f(x))$ gets sent to $x \mapsto f(sx)$. So what do you mean with your the left/right-module comment?

Comment: @SMM If you can give a counter example I am also satisfied!

Comment: @SMM the question is tagged commutative-algebra so I assume all rings are commutative

Comment: @Christopher You are right, I'm sorry.

Comment: I'm not convinced it matters for the question, but why do you conclude that $M_{|R}$ is free? Even in the case $R = S$ then this doesn't hold - e.g. if $R = S = \Bbb Z$ then $\Bbb Z / 2 \Bbb Z$ is a finite $S$-module which is not a free $R$-module.

Comment: @Christopher That's just part of the assumption.